# mqtt.client:connect() "not established" callback is unexpectedly called after a disconnect

Tags: lua, mqtt, nodemcu

The documentation for mqtt.client:connect() states that the last arg is a "callback function for when the connection could not be established".

I have a case where mqtt.client:connect() succeeds, so the "not established" callback is not called (correct behavior).  But, later, when my mqtt broker goes down, the "not established" callback function gets unexpectedly activated.

I have the following code:

```
function handle_mqtt_error (client, reason)
  print("mqtt connect failed, reason = "..reason..". Trying again shortly.")
  tmr.create():alarm(10 * 1000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, do_mqtt_connect)
end

function do_mqtt_connect ()
  print("connecting---")
  m:connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, 1, function(client)
      print("mqtt connected")
      client:publish("topic/status", "online", 1, 1)
    end,
    handle_mqtt_error
    )
  print("returning---")
end

-- init mqtt client
m = mqtt.Client(MQTT_CLIENT_ID, 120, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASS)

-- connect to mqtt
print("Starting Test")
do_mqtt_connect()
```

I see the output from the test begin, as expected, with:

```
Starting Test
connecting---
returning---
mqtt connected
```

At this point, I kill my mqtt broker, and I unexpectedly see:

```
mqtt connect failed, reason = -5. Trying again shortly.
connecting---
returning---
mqtt connect failed, reason = -5. Trying again shortly.
connecting---
returning---
```

And, happily, but unexpectedly, when I restart my broker, I see:

```
mqtt connected
```

So, it appears that handle_mqtt_error() is not only called "when the connection could not be established".  It appears that it also be called if mqtt.client:connect() successfully establishes a connection, then the connection is later broken.

======= New Information =======

I downloaded the "dev" tree and used the Docker image to build the firmware.  Within mqtt.c, I enabled NODE_DBG.  The interesting lines are:

```
enter mqtt_socket_reconnected.
mqtt connect failed, reason = -5. Trying again shortly.
enter mqtt_socket_disconnected.
leave mqtt_socket_disconnected.
leave mqtt_socket_reconnected.
```

The "mqtt connect failed..." message is printed by handle_mqtt_error(), which is my "connect failed" callback.

Here's my theory.  When my test starts, do_mqtt_connect() calls mqtt_socket_connect(), which does this:

```
espconn_regist_reconcb(pesp_conn, mqtt_socket_reconnected);
```

This sets reconnect_callback (in app/lwip/app/espconn.c).  Later, after my broker goes down and comes back up, espconn_tcp_reconnect() is called (in app/lwip/app/espconn_tcp.c).  It calls the reconnect_callback, which is mqtt_socket_reconnected(), which calls handle_mqtt_error().

So, I think the end result doesn't match the documentation, but it works out okay for me.  If the behavior did match the documentation, I would just add some Lua code to handle the "offline" event, and try to reestablish the mqtt connection.  I just thought someone might be interested if the behavior doesn't match the documentation.

Comment: You don't mention the NodeMCU version you're using but I don't think it's any of these: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mqtt The documentation has a paragraph about auto-reconnect though: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/mqtt/#mqttclientconnect

Comment: Thanks Marcel.  It is a custom build by frightanic.com from the master.  It was built on 2018-01-17 14:46.  The documentation says that auto-reconnect defaults to 0, and is deprecated.  In the example snippit (above), the call to m:connect() does not include an arg for auto-reconnect, so it should be 0.  I also ran a version where I included a 0 for the auto-reconnect arg in the m:connect() call.  I got the same unexpected behavior.

Comment: I edited the post to add some trace information and a theory of what is happening.

Comment: Isn't this related to fixes #2256 and #2262 at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed? You could build a firmware from the dev branch to verify.

Comment: Yes, it is solved by #2262.